Logica para realizar un sorteo del amigo invisible con exclusiones
estoy desarrollando con python la lógica necesaria para sortear el amigo invisible y me gustaria hacer algo asi:
Imaginemos 3 participantes:

pepe
martin
antonio

Primer Caso
Ahora con estos 3 participantes digamos que no queremos que a pepe le toque martin es decir agregamos una exclusion pepe para que no le toque martin.

pepe exclusiones [2]
martin
antonio

PD: Esto no significa que martin no le regale a pepe. Pepe NO le regalara a martin pero martin SI puede regalar a pepe.
IMPORTANTE que en este caso concreto a pepe le toque regalar a antonio, porque si a martin le toca regalar a antonio pepe se va a quedar sin regalarle a nadie
Segundo caso
Tambien el programa tendra que tener en cuenta que las exclusiones no sea abusivas, por ejemplo esto no funcionaria porque 2 personas no pueden regalarle a una sola ya que va a haber 1 a quien no le va a regalar nadie

pepe exclusiones [2]
martin exclusiones [1]
antonio exclusiones [1]

Pruebas
De momento llevo algo como esto pero falla en el primer caso diciendo que las exclusiones son abusivas sin llegar a serlo
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, exclusiones=None):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.exclusiones = exclusiones if exclusiones is not None else []

def sorteo_amigo_invisible(personas):
    if len(personas) < 3:
        print("Error: Debe haber al menos 3 personas para realizar el sorteo.")
        return
    
    personas_disponibles = personas.copy()
    
    asignaciones = {}
    
    for persona in personas:
        personas_disponibles_para_asignar = [p for p in personas_disponibles if p.nombre != persona.nombre and p.nombre not in persona.exclusiones]
        
        if not personas_disponibles_para_asignar:
            print("Error: No se puede realizar el sorteo debido a exclusiones demasiado restrictivas.")
            return
        
        amigo_invisible = random.choice(personas_disponibles_para_asignar)
        
        asignaciones[persona.nombre] = amigo_invisible.nombre
        
        personas_disponibles.remove(amigo_invisible)
    
    for persona, amigo in asignaciones.items():
        print(f"{persona} le ha tocado regalar a {amigo}.")

personas = [
    Persona("Juan", [2]),
    Persona("María", []),
    Persona("Pedro"),
    Persona("Ana", [3]),
    Persona("Luis")
]

sorteo_amigo_invisible(personas)


En todos los casos debes tratar de evitar las relaciones circulares o mutuas: (A -> B) y (B -> A). La cantidad de emparejamientos será igual a la cantidad de personas, entonces, si la cantidad de personas es impar no puede haber cantidad de relaciones mútuas - 1, ya que siempre quedará uno solo. Si la cantidad es par no habrá ese problema pero será poco atractivo el juego.

Entiendo, y de hecho lo estuve probando antes de llegar a esta logica, y  claro el problema es que en ocasiones el resultado es algo como:
A -> C
C -> B
B -> A

@Anthonyx82 Acaso no es A -> C C -> B B -> A el único resultado válido para tres personas?? De cualquier otra manera estarías teniendo a una persona autoregalándose.  Por cierto, si el valor por defecto de exclusiones es [] puedes ahorrarte el ternario comprobando si es None, directamente lo asignas.

Este problema se puede resolver con backtracking, la forma más sencilla es utilizando un while y una pila

@Yussef si estoy buscando información sobre ello veremos si consigo hacerlo, muchas gracias

Quizás te ayude: Script amigo invisible (secret´s Santa)

@JorgeLuis gracias finalmente lo hice asi con recursividad cuando termine el código completo lo subo a la pregunta

Finalmente llegue a este codigo, lo se es extremadamente complejo y hay partes que yo ni siguiera recuerdo, pero por si a alguien pueda ayudarle
def generar_combinaciones(participantes, exclusiones, asignaciones=[], index=0):
    if index == len(participantes):
        yield asignaciones[:]
        return
    
    participante_actual = participantes[index]
    for posible_asignacion in participantes:
        if (posible_asignacion != participante_actual and
                (not exclusiones.get(participante_actual) or posible_asignacion not in exclusiones[participante_actual])):
            asignaciones.append((participante_actual, posible_asignacion))
            yield from generar_combinaciones(participantes, exclusiones, asignaciones, index + 1)
            asignaciones.pop()


def validar_combinaciones(combinaciones):
    for asignacion in combinaciones:
        regalados = {x[1] for x in asignacion}
        if len(regalados) != len(asignacion):
            return False
    return True


def sorteo_amigo_invisible(participantes, exclusiones):
    combinaciones = generar_combinaciones(participantes, exclusiones)
    for combinacion in combinaciones:
        if validar_combinaciones(combinacion):
            yield combinacion


# Ejemplo de uso
participantes = ["pepe", "martin", "antonio", "fran" ]
exclusiones = {
    "pepe": ["martin", "antonio"],
    "martin": [],
    "antonio": [],
    "fran": []
}

for resultado in sorteo_amigo_invisible(participantes, exclusiones):
    print(resultado)


Basicamente el codigo genera todas las posibles combinaciones y de hay puedes escojer una de ellas de forma aleatoria
